# Focus input Safari Mobile focuses with box shadow but not with cursor inside the input field

Tags: jquery, focus

I am focusing my input field when I touch magnifying glass (`#searchIconHeaderPress`). But it only focuses the box shadow on the input field (Bootstrap 4 style).

But it does not focuses the CURSOR inside the input field only when I click inside the input field again while the box shadow ONLY shows. I want it to focus with the cursor inside the inputfield for the user friendly experience, without touching inside the input again is this possible?

```
$("#searchIconHeaderPress").click(function () {

      setTimeout(function() {
              $('.searchInputHeader').focus();
            }, 500);
});
```

It does not work at all without the timeOut because I have icons effects on when I click on the magnifying glass.

Comment: Show more code and try a console.log somewhere.

Comment: @FSDford Thanks for your answer i thought my question was clear. But i am thinking that because i do not know this should work then? Are you telling me it should focus with the keyboard opened and cursor inside the input when the `.focus();` gets executed? Where should i put console.log? Sorry i am a beginner.

Comment: @FSDford You still here?